# In TCL ... If define variable like << set a_$b 15 >>. Then I dont know how can I use value of this variable, $[a$b]

Tags: variables, set, tcl

```
set someDataList [list 1 2 3]
######$MaxNoOfVariable is not finite, it depend on [llength $someDataList] that get diffrents amount from input text file,for example [list 1 2 3 4 ... ] up to => 5 or 10 or 1000 ...
set MaxNoOfVariable [llength $someDataList]
for {set NoOfVariablesNeed 0} {$NoOfVariablesNeed<$MaxNoOfVariable} {incr NoOfVariablesNeed} {


set A_$NoOfVariablesNeed [expr ($NoOfVariablesNeed+2)]; # A_0 = 2 , A_1 = 3 , A_2 = 4 , A_3 = 5 , A_4 = 6 , ....

}
### Last part
puts "$A_0"
puts "$A_1"
puts "$A_2"
```

Up to this line it's ok. But becuase the [llength $someListData] maybe change in 
other situation and I cant predict it, I need to use some code like this instead of the last part ...

```
set i 0 
while {$i < [llength $someListData]} {
puts "$A_$i";  # Goal is : $A_0 , $A_1 , $A_2      XXXXXXXXX Here is my problem  XXXXXXXXXXXX
set i [expr ($i+1)]
    }
```

I cant call the value of variable...

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427261/in-tcl-cant-read-a-variable-when-its-name-is-comprised-of-another-variable

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer can be command eval like this :
eval "puts $$b"

```
set i 0
while {$i < [llength $someListData]} {

set b A_${i}

eval "puts $$b"

set i [expr ($i+1)]
}
```

Its work good, but I think I can find better way for this job. Thanks alot...

Comment: When you save the data, I would rather use arrays like A(1) instead of A_1

Comment: Use of `eval` is usually a warning flag in modern Tcl; there's a better way for every common case. The way to do it here is `puts [set $b]` (or `puts [set A_$i]`) — single argument `set` reads its variable — but the case you're describing is _definitely_ better done with arrays.